# Nodejs how to handle multiple parallel requests incase of blocking process

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, server

I am doing a small project in which a user makes a http request to my server after which I get and process some data from three different servers and then return the summed up result to the client.

Everything works fine accept when more than two clients make requests at same time, all clients are not able to get response and faces timeout error.

How to handle this thing .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not make bloking requests in node.js it is supposed to be async by default. You can add some load balancer if you have to do bloking operations, but it is better to switch to async ones. Care to share more about your case? Maybe some code?

Comment: The request being made to three different servers are asynchronous but  their result have to be processed and summed up before sending it to user. Is there a different way to to do this ?

Comment: So i guess that just takes a lot of time to do this "summing up"? Then i would recommend to split computation in few less expensive blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i get it. I would recommend using es6 promises for that kind of stuff. 
You can use [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) and [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to make http request to other servers.

And then just:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var bluebird = require('bluebird');

bluebird
.all(rp('http://www.google.com'), rp('http://example.com'))
.then(function (googleResponse, exampleResponse) {
    // Some computation
    return someResult;
})
.then(function (previousResult) {
    // Some more computation
    return someResult;
});
```

Basically what you want is making part of computation, returning with then and allowing node to takeover, then in next then doing other part of computation and so on. If you split your process into few small blocks you should be able to have less blocking.

Other than that you can checkout node clustering, it is quite simple process that allows you to handle server load between few workers:
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-a-node-js-cluster-for-speeding-up-your-apps/